# How to use Multi-Mapper to create multiple one to many object hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I have my 2 models like below

```
public  class FItem
        {
            public FItem() { }

            public int RecordId { get; set; }
            public int MarketId { get; set; }
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
            public string ItemFamily { get; set; }
            public string HoverFamily { get; set; }
            public string ItemDesc { get; set; }                

            public IEnumerable<FSubsystem> FSubsystems { get; set; }
       }

   public class FSubsystem
        {
            public FSubsystem() { }

            public int FSubsystemId { get; set; }
            public int RecordId { get; set; } //Foreign key
            public int supplierId { get; set; }
            public int SubSystemTypeId { get; set; }
            public double Percentage { get; set; }
            public double? Value { get; set; }
        }

 public class FReferences
 {
     public FReferences() { }

     public int RecordID { get; set; } //Foreign key
     public int SourceID { get; set; }
     public DateTime SourceDate { get; set; }
     public string Reference { get; set; } 
     public int? ReferenceID { get; set; }
 }
```

and I use dapper to fetch the data and put into objects . code is as belolw

```
using (var multi = mapperConnection.QueryMultiple("USP_FetchMarketRecords", parameters, (SqlTransaction)null, 1000000, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
            {
                    IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FItem> FItem = multi.Read<MarketRecord.FItem>().ToList();                        
                    IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FSubsystem> FSubsystem = multi.Read<MarketRecord.FSubsystem>().ToList();                        
            }
```

Now I want to get the subsystems for each record id and put them in FSubsystems  property of Fitem . How can I do this ?

Here I am showing only one one to many relationship to FItem thats Fsubsystem . But I have many one to many tables to Fitem like FReferenc ,FUnit etc . For all foreign key is RecordId itelf.

Can this be done through linq query ? or should I use some diff technique ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dapper doesn't include anything built in to reconstruct parent/child relationships from different sets.

You can probably generalize the scenario something like:

```
static void ApplyParentChild<TParent, TChild, TId>(
    this IEnumerable<TParent> parents, IEnumerable<TChild> children,
    Func<TParent, TId> id, Func<TChild, TId> parentId,
    Action<TParent, TChild> action)
{
    var lookup = parents.ToDictionary(id);
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        TParent parent;
        if (lookup.TryGetValue(parentId(child), out parent))
            action(parent, child);
    }
}
```

so if we had:

```
List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent> {
    new Parent { Id = 1 },
    new Parent { Id = 2 }
};
List<Child> children = new List<Child> {
    new Child { Id = 3, ParentId = 1},
    new Child { Id = 4, ParentId = 2},
    new Child { Id = 5, ParentId = 1}
};
```

You could use:

```
parents.ApplyParentChild(children, p => p.Id, c => c.ParentId,
    (p,c) => p.Children.Add(c));
```

Comment: But my all childs not of same structure . I will update my question

Comment: Please check the updated questrion . FSubsystem & FReferences are of diff structure.